# Powershell Printout only certain section of lines

Tags: powershell

I see a lot of "grab last word", "grab first/last X characters" or "grab lines that contain XXX" however I've been unable to find a solution here for my problem.
For example, my text file contains line like

```
[0000001] item_title apple_juice_2L_concentrate 0x000581
[0000002] item_description 98%_reconstituted_apple_juice 0x00585
[0000003] item_title orange_juice_2L_natural 0x000679
[0000004] item_description 100%_fresh_squeeze_orange_juice 0x00985
[0000005] item_title apple_juice_1L_natural 0x000429
[0000006] item_description 100%_natural_apple_juice_cloudy 0x00587
```

how would I achieve a printout like this while cutting out the junk i dont want like the [0000001] and the 0x000581

```
apple_juice_2L_concentrate
apple_juice_1L_natural
```

I'm currently using:

```
Get-Content -Path H:\"inventory management"\juice\juices.txt | Where-Object {$_ -like '*item_title apple_juice*'}
```

which returns

```
[0000001] item_title apple_juice_2L_concentrate 0x000581
[0000005] item_title apple_juice_1L_natural 0x000429
```

Appreciate your time!

Pretty picture for reference. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cotjv.png

Answered own question with assistance from other answers here.

Comment: do you only want the apple items or do you want all the `item_title` values? the 1st would match what you show, but the 2nd would also include `orange_juice_2L_natural`.

Comment: on the `grab 3rd item` idea ... try this >>> `$YourString.Split(' ')[2]` <<< that would give you the3rd item in each line.

Comment: i can do the line filter fine, as in, if i only want apple juice i can do that as shown, if i want to do only orange juice i would change it to range juice, or if i wanted both id just use item_title. but more specifiaclly i just want to be able to grab X portion of the line. to which your 2nd comment looks more like what im after. ill try now though i don't know where to add that section in? can you elaborate please?

Comment: i tried this >>> {$_.Split -like ('*item_title apple_juice*')[2]} <<< and a few other iterations of moving the stuff around but i can't seem to work out where it goes. it  seems the formatting in comments turn my * into italics tho, still the same thing from OP

Comment: it looks like `Bill_Stewart` has an answer for you. [*grin*] since his uses regex & your original question seems more focused on "grab item 3", i will post an answer that uses the `.Split()` string method so you can see what i meant. his is better, tho! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to get the item title from first line and item description from line after it? If that's what you want to do, here's an example:

```
# Sample data; replace this with Get-Content, etc.
$inputData = @"
[0000001] item_title apple_juice_2L_concentrate 0x000581
[0000002] item_description 98%_reconstituted_apple_juice 0x00585
[0000003] item_title orange_juice_2L_natural 0x000679
[0000004] item_description 100%_fresh_squeeze_orange_juice 0x00985
[0000005] item_title apple_juice_1L_natural 0x000429
[0000006] item_description 100%_natural_apple_juice_cloudy 0x00587
"@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $inputData.Count; $i++ ) {
  if ( $inputData[$i] -match ' item_description ' ) {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
    "item_title"       = [Regex]::Match($inputData[$i - 1],' item_title (.+) 0x').Groups[1].Value
    "item_description" = [Regex]::Match($inputData[$i],' item_description (.+) 0x').Groups[1].Value
    }
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
item_title                 item_description
----------                 ----------------
apple_juice_2L_concentrate 98%_reconstituted_apple_juice
orange_juice_2L_natural    100%_fresh_squeeze_orange_juice
apple_juice_1L_natural     100%_natural_apple_juice_cloudy
```

This pattern assumes that there's a line in the input that contains the string `item_description` and that the line before it contains the string `item_title`.

Comment: No my goal is exactly as explained in the OP, thanks though.

Comment: The OP isn't really very clear as to what your goal is. ("Cutting out the junk" is not a technical description.) Without a very explicit technical definition of what you are trying to do, "guessing game" questions are tiresome for both the questioner and the one trying to answer.

Comment: It's extremely clear if you read it correctly and not assume i want things i'm not asking for. I put some pretty colours to help you better understand. https://imgur.com/fSRaH4R.png

Comment: I might suggest that if two different people had trouble understanding the specifics of the question, that perhaps it isn't quite as clear as you think it is. I will bow out now...

Comment: Or they simply shared the common trait of not ascertaining what is being asked and assuming they know what the OP thinks they want. Like you for example: "Is your goal to get the item title from first line and item description from line after it? If that's what you want to do, here's an example" . No, that's not what my goal was.

Comment: I will pass along a piece of free advice: My recommendation is to use a less combative approach. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

this uses the `.Split()` string method to split on the spaces, then grabs the 3rd item [index = 2 since arrays start @ 0]. finally, it puts that into a `$Results` collection. you can use that whole collection OR filter it with `$Results -match 'apple'` to get the items that have apple in them.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
[0000001] item_title apple_juice_2L_concentrate 0x000581
[0000002] item_description 98%_reconstituted_apple_juice 0x00585
[0000003] item_title orange_juice_2L_natural 0x000679
[0000004] item_description 100%_natural_apple_juice_cloudy 0x00985
[0000005] item_title apple_juice_1L_natural 0x000429
[0000006] item_description 100%_natural_apple_juice_cloudy 0x00585
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$TargetPhrase = 'item_title'

$Results = $InStuff -match $TargetPhrase |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Split(' ')[2]
        }

$Results
'=' * 20
# if you want only the apple items
$Results -match 'apple'
```

output ...

```
apple_juice_2L_concentrate
orange_juice_2L_natural
apple_juice_1L_natural
====================
apple_juice_2L_concentrate
apple_juice_1L_natural
```

---

here's an alternate way that does exactly the same thing but uses part of the OPs code since he refuses to abandon that awkward, wrong-headed method. [*grin*] this presumes the file has been loaded with `Get-Content` into the `$InStuff` variable. if you really want things smashed into one line ... you can do that rather silly thing if you wish.

```
$TargetPhrase = 'item_title apple'
$InStuff |
    Where-Object {
        $_ -match $TargetPhrase
        } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Split(' ')[2]
        }
```

output ...

```
apple_juice_2L_concentrate
apple_juice_1L_natural
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated that this file has thousands of lines like this, not just the 6. So I want to be able to simply have an output that filters whatever i choose, ie lines that have "item_title" but also "apple_juice" but clear out all the junk so all it reads as the end result is line1: apple_juice_2L_concentrate, line2: apple_juice_1L_natural etc. My original code works great except that is has all the junk in it i don't want.

Comment: @Napalm - so ... what is different from the 2nd part of my answer? the 1st part shows that ALL the lines are stored with the short target string. the 2nd part shows that you can then filter it with any added string - apple, for instance. ///// if you want it done in one step ... then change the `$TargetPhrase` to match what you want to filter by. [*grin*]

Comment: all i want to do is change my existing code so it grabs the 3rd section only, not the entire line. everything else is working fine.

Comment: @Napalm - your code does not work well. change it to match what i used and it will work.

Comment: so what you telling me is theres no possible way to change >>>Where-Object {$_ -like '*item_title apple_juice*'}<<< to only pull the 3rd section? because thats all i want. nothing else needs to change.

Comment: Which parts of yours do I remove to add back the Get-Content?

Comment: @Napalm - nope, just that you can make the changes by taking the idea in my code and replacing yours with one that works. your code**_can_** be forced to work ... [*grin*]

Comment: I did, i woudlnt be asking if it helped.

Comment: The only thing my code doesn't do that I want it to do is pull the 3rd section only, not the whole line. Pretty simple concept.  I don't understand why both of you are adding all this extra stuff I didn't ask for and acting like it's my issue.

Comment: @Napalm - it looks like refusal to think to me. i have been wrong many times, so this could easily be another. [*grin*] since i can't think of anything else to say, i will go back to lurking. i sincerely wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you a solution :

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header ID, RowType, Libelle, Reference  | 
        where {$_.RowType -eq 'item_title' -AND $_.Libelle -match 'apple_juice'} | select Libelle
```

Comment: This works also the same as my answer though adding an unnecessary header and taking at least 5x as long to execute the output. Good job for actually answering the question :D

Comment: i prefert Always work with object and not with string, its better for export, transformation etc (its the PowerShell force versus shell unix). If you want remove header you can do : (Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header ID, RowType, Libelle, Reference  | 
        where {$_.RowType -eq 'item_title' -and $_.Libelle  -match 'apple_juice'}).Libelle

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer a different perspective using `Select-String`:

```
(Select-String -Path 'H:\inventory management\juice\juices.txt' -pattern "(?<=item_title\s*)apple_juice[^\s]*").Matches.Value
```

This could be modified to allow variables:

```
$category = 'item_title'
$juice = 'apple_juice'
(Select-String -Path 'H:\inventory management\juice\juices.txt' -pattern "(?<=$category\s*)$juice[^\s]*").Matches.Value
```

Comment: yeah, i like :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the answer that should've been provided:

```
$InStuff = Get-Content -Path 'H:\inventory management\juice\juices.txt' 

$TargetPhrase = 'item_title'

$Results = $InStuff -match $TargetPhrase |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Split(' ')[2]
        }

$Results -match 'apple_juice'
```

Comment: try my last solution (one row) ;)

Comment: Length or sticking to one line was never the issue for me like some people claim it is, though as always, the less the better. I tested yours but unfortunately it reports back every line that contains "apple", this would include description lines. I only wanted the lines that have "item_name" in the 2nd position and "apple_juice" in the 3rd. What i linked above as an answer works exactly as i asked in op :D

Comment: I have modified my code for test item_name too. But your example is not really exact same if the result is here.Imagine if you have this row [0000007] item_description apple_juice_1L_natural_item_title 0x000429  … You must test second column and not all row content for keep a exact comportment. And you split all row with item_title for test in the end the apple_juice…. Why test all rows for that ;)

Comment: Time to execute my answer, 12s, time to execute your script, 63s. That's why. End of the day, i managed to get what i actually asked for and that's all that matters. I'm out :D